# Django query manytomanyfield in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How can I query a manytomanyfield in a Django template?

For example, this if statement doesn't work (I know I can't call functions with arguments in Django templates), but this shows what I'd like to do:

template.html

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.likes.filter(user=user) %}
        You like this post
    {% else %}
        <a>Click here to like this post</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class User(Model):
    # fields

class Post(Model):
    likes = ManyToManyField(User)
```

Comment: Standard django template system does not allow to call methods with parameters. You can use Jinja2 if would like to call code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do what you are looking for, you could do the following:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if user in post.likes.distinct %}
        You like this post
    {% else %}
        <a>Click here to like this post</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, you could use Greg's approach.  The advantage of his answer is that it would scale better when you get into very large datasets.  This approach does not require you to write any custom filters.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because you appear to be writing python code in a template... you need to either run the loop in your view and pass a list of posts and their information to the template, or write a template filter that determines whether a certain user likes a post. For example:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def is_liked_by(post, user):
    return bool(post.likes.filter(user=user))
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post|is_liked_by:request.user %}
        You like this post
    {% else %}
        <a>Click here to like this post</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using [`.exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) instead of `bool(post.likes.filter(user=user))` on the query set.  It's marginally faster and this seems like the case it was designed for.  It would be used like so: `return post.likes.filter(user=user).exists()`